# Is there a generic approach to count aws cloud resources on an account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

I need to list the amount of *resources* that are part of an AWS account in Go, while a *resource* should be anything that has a price tag on it and can be counted, e.g.

- S3 buckets
- EC2 instances
- RDS instances
- ELBs
- ...

state, region, type and tags are not relevant for this kind of overview, just the raw numbers.

I could of course use the Go SDK and use each corresponding service to get the instances and sum them up, but this would mean lots of boilerplate code and lots of time to create it.

My question: Is there any more *generic* approach to get the item counts for *most* services (fine if it doesn't work for all) that can be used with the Go SDK, so I don't have to recode the same query for each service manually?

Comment: No. The Go SDK is a Go binding for the AWS API. The AWS API has no single call to get the "count of all resources", as that's a pretty meaningless metric - I'm curious what value you might try to get from it.

Comment: I feel your pain ... you would think a trillion dollar business would have better tooling especially their api and its doc as well as the aws forum which is tightly embedded with that 1990's feel - so sad ... Amazon are you listening